# Loading a RavenDB document without CLR type

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to load a document by its id from a domain that does not have the CLR type that was stored.

The original structure looks something like this:

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public string SomeValue {get;set;}
    public List<Data> Data {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Data { }
public class Data1 : Data 
{
    public string SomeOtherValue {get;set;}
}
```

Now in my second project which does not have access to this structure i try to load it by using the duck-typing features of raven with a class that looks the same.

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public string SomeValue {get;set;}
    //public List<Data> Data {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Data { }
public class Data1 : Data 
{
    public string SomeOtherValue {get;set;}
}
```

If i do not include the Data parameter (as above) in this class it loads fine, but if i do include it it fails with an error saying it doesn't know about the original type stored ("Could not load assembly 'OriginalAssemblyName'"). Is there any way to make raven duck-type the list of objects as well instead of trying to cast it to a type i don't have access to?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on something very similar and stumbled across this.  Loading the object from the session as a JObject seems to work ok for me.  sesssion.Load(id).  I am trying to do something a little more complicated and still having issues.  Ongoing thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/y3-SVB18xVg

Comment: What i ended up doing was to load the list of data as List<object>, then write an extension method that retrieved the properties of the DynamicJsonObject and tried to populate the specified block, if it has the same properties as the block i asked for, it returned it. Not the most elegant solution but it worked for what i needed the data for.